# Jenkins console execute shell running as root user instead of jenkins user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins, npm

my jenkins test job console execute shell look like this;

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(id)
npm -v
```

when I build this job the console output shown as;

```
uid=497(jenkins) gid=495(jenkins) groups=495(jenkins)
3.10.10
```

when I ssh into jenkins ec2 machine and then switch to jenkins user and run the command npm -v I got the different version of npm.
I suspect jenkins console execute shell run as root user shell where it picked up the npm version of root user.

when I run `whoami` and `which npm` I got the results on jenkins console as `jenkins` and `/usr/bin/npm` respectively, but while on jenkins ec2 instance when I run these commands on jenkins user shell I got the results as `jenkins` and `~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/bin/npm`. please assist me to understand why I got two different results

Please assist. I appreciate your time

Comment: Hi, try to run eg. `whoami` or `which npm` and you will see - who is the user, and where npm is being executed :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. when I run 'whoami' and 'which npm' I got the results on jenkins console as 'jenkins' and '/usr/bin/npm' respectively, but while on jenkins ec2 instance when I run these commands on jenkins user shell I got the results as 'jenkins' and '~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/bin/npm'. please assist me to understand why I got two different results. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for outputs, maybe add these info into question directly via edit, for more clues for others :). Well, it looks like npm variable is set and delivered via jenkins, usually via tools in global settings, or in case of `nvm wrapper` (or npm wrapper, not sure how exactly it is called) each job has the configuration

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Added info to my question as you suggested. I have checked global tool config, but npm variable is not set anywhere. Also nvm wrapper is not configured on the job configuration.

Comment: well, commonly output means, its running under same user- `jenkins`, but using different npm, in first case global one, in second specific delivered by nodejs, then maybe in `build environment` - `Provide Node & npm bin/ folder to PATH` ? referring to jenkins global config `Tools configuration` -> `NodeJS` 
But I am not sure how you can impact that actually, it looks like its having some predefined location for installation

Comment: Appreciate your prompt response. We have not specified path in either build env or global tool configuration. I am just curious to know how jenkins pickup this specific path in its execute shell. The impact is that consider the scenario where I need to install npm pacakges . If I install it in ec2 as jenkins user, it wont reflect in jenkins console.

Comment: Hmm, strange, then I dont have any more ideas :), but anyway thanks for outputs

Comment: Thank you for your time and inputs. I will update here if I decode this issue. Thanks a lot.